# Aliasing a java package name in clojure

Tags: clojure

Given a java package x.y.z, can I alias x.y.z to a shorter name, so that i can then refer to java classes inside the package as my-alias.MyJavaClass.

If that isn't possible, I could just `import` all classes into my namespace, but I don't want to specify the names of each class manually, and the clojure API docs doesn't seem clear on whether it's possible to `import` all classes in a package automatically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't any functionality for this (yet). Java packages are in a different namespace than Clojure's, so the usual alias tricks won't work.

What you can do is import each class, which lets you avoid the full package+class name:

```
(import [java.io File Writer Reader])
(new File "/")
; #<File />
```

Rich provides his reasons for not supporting `(import [java.io.*])` [here](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/msg/ddca7ec56ea8b51f).