# Can I use require :as with Java interop?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aliasing a java package name in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698209/aliasing-a-java-package-name-in-clojure)

If I have a Java API like this:

```
com.very.long.and.boring.names.Abc
com.very.long.and.boring.names.Def
com.very.long.and.boring.names.Ghi
```

Can I use it from Clojure (1.4.0) with a "fake" namespace like this:

```
(foo/Abc)
(foo/Def)
(foo/Ghi)
```

I don't want to *(use 'com.very.long.and.boring.names)* because Abc / Def / Ghi may clash with my Clojure functions.  So basically I want to "map" "com.very.long.and.boring.names" to "foo".

I tried several things at the REPL but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that this functionality exists as yet.

However if the purpose is to use the Class object at runtime, you can always just do:

```
(def s java.lang.String)

(.newInstance s)
=> ""
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're basically asking this same question:

[Aliasing a java package name in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698209/aliasing-a-java-package-name-in-clojure)

Apparently the functionality doesn't actually exist yet...

However, class names usually start with capital letters, whereas function names are lower-case by convention. Unless the Java classes or your functions aren't following these conventions then you shouldn't have any conflicts.